# Validating input parameters against route bound model

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I have a small question concerning validation.
there is an api route `POST /api/document/{document}/link` it accepts an array of document IDs (`{"ids": [1, 2, 3]}`) to be linked to the Document bound to the route. I validate this array as follows

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'ids' => 'required|array',
            'ids.*' => 'numeric|exists:documents,id'
        ];
    }
```

The thing is the Document model has a `partner` attribute and it's not possible to link together documents from different partners. What I want is to check if the documents passed (by their IDs) belong to the same partner as the bound Document. I would like to validate this within the FormRequest. Is it possible?

Comment: Is it just an array of id's? what does the input look like exactly

Comment: Yes the input is just an array of IDs. `{"ids": [1, 2, 3]}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is what I ended up with:

```
public function rules()
    {
        /** @var Document $document */
        $document = $this->route('document');

        return [
            'ids' => ['required', 'array'],
            'ids.*' => ['required', 'numeric', Rule::exists('documents','id')->where('partner_id', $document->partner_id)],
        ];
    }
```

As it turned out the case is described in Laravel docs here https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-exists. I just needed to customize the query executed to ensure that both the passed `id` and `partner_id` exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these for your rules:

```php
'ids' => [
    'required',
    'array'
],
'ids.*' => [
    'required',
    'exists:documents,id'

],
'ids.*.partner_id' => [
    Rule::in([$document->partner_id])
]
```

this wil validate your id matches with the numbers in the array, since we only put the id from the route given `$document` in there it should match or return failed.

Comment: I cannot use `'ids.*.partner_id' => [Rule::in([$document->partner_id])]` because the input array lacks `partner_id` parameter. Anyway, thank you so much for showing me the right direction. I'll post my final code as an answer.